# What is the purpose of jQuery clean and cleanData methods?

Tags: jquery

[jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js) has **clean** and **cleanData** methods. What is the purpose of jQuery **clean** and **cleanData** methods?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Both are *internal*, *undocumented* methods, so you should not use them or rely on their current behavior, because they might change or disappear in the future.

That said, `clean()` sanitizes the markup in the document fragments that are created from the HTML strings passed to some functions (most notably to [$()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) itself).

`cleanData()` frees the [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) associated with elements when they disappear from the DOM, e.g. through [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/), or [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2).

Comment: Not using them. I was curious because I'm getting errors inside of clean method because of html that was constructed in my own javascript. Hence I'm curious about these methods.

Comment: @dev, that might mean your markup is invalid. I'd suggest you double-check it.

Comment: Weird because it was working fine in previous version. I just upgraded from 1.4.2. to 1.6.2.  I found the problem and fixed it but still confused on why it worked before.

Comment: So clean sanitizes markup that was build dynamically using jQuery $()?

Comment: @dev, yes, it does. It fixes whitespace and removes `<tbody>` elements generated by IE browsers, among other things.

Comment: Does this unbind events as well?

Comment: @Johannes, I double-checked in 1.11.0 and `cleanData()` is also responsible for cleaning event handlers, yes. Keep in mind, however, this is an internal implementation detail that might have changed thirty-five minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

From "Secrets of the Javascript Ninja"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function clone() {
       var ret = this.map(function () {
         if (!jQuery.support.noCloneEvent && !jQuery.isXMLDoc(this)) {
           var clone = this.cloneNode(true),
           container = document.createElement("div");
           container.appendChild(clone);
           return jQuery.clean([container.innerHTML])[0];
          }
          else
          return this.cloneNode(true);
          });
          var clone = ret.find("*").andSelf().each(function () {
          if (this[ expando ] !== undefined)
             this[ expando ] = null;
          });
          return ret;
          }
</script>
```

"... the preceding code uses JQuery's Jquery.clean method, which converts an HTML string into a DOM structure"