# When does a scope naturally get destroyed in angularjs lifecycle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I see this type of code a lot in angular modules

```
scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
  //undind listener here
});
```

My understanding is that whenever the scope is about to be destroyed it broadcasts a `$destroy` event allowing you to clean up any code that may continue to run after the destruction of the scope which would create memory leaks.

My question is, when does the scope naturally get destroyed in an angularjs app.  All the documentation I can find from the website is that you can manually call `$destroy` to remove a scope, but this seems to suggest that it will happen at some point automatically.  When would that be?

Comment: When you change routes/states the $scope of the previous controller gets destroyed automatically.

Comment: Are there any other times or is that it?

Comment: Yep. As seen in the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy) this event can be called by any scope instance, for example a directive scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope is tied to HTML elements during compilation. $compile needs a scope to compile an element. Elements could be nested. Some get new scope other inherit.

Scope gets destroyed when elements are removed from DOM.

To be precise: A `$destroy` handlers are called on `jQuery.cleanData` which AngularJS redefines and calls after it does its cleanup - aka acting in destroying the scope.

`cleanData` function is called when an element is removed from the DOM.

[What is the purpose of jQuery clean and cleanData methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083884/what-is-the-purpose-of-jquery-clean-and-cleandata-methods)